# Paint Scrollbale Infinite Generating Grid

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am trying to draw a grid of rectangles and I want to be able to draw them off the screen in all directions and then be able to scroll this, changing which are actually in the screen without having to redraw every frame.

Comment: huh? what actually do you need?

Comment: To be able to draw in the center of a page and scroll all around it

Comment: use View.scrollBy(int x, int y) / View.scrollTo(int x, int y)

Comment: also GestureDetector can be helpful for scrolling implementation